Would I be breaking Scottish law if I padlocked a gate to a business
A large multinational has not paid invoices, (now a year overdue). I have contacted them on multiple occasions only to have emails go unanswered and calls disconnected.
Would I be prosecuted if I padlocked the gate to the site, (Scotland) and which law would be applicable?

Lots of key facts missing here. Who owns the land? What is the relationship of the company to the land? Are unpaid invoices for rent? If not, for what? What do the contracts that are the basis of the invoices say you can do? Are the invoices disputed? Is the company in bankruptcy? Have you written them a letter to their official notice address?

Comments on this question indicate "case is going through small claims court" and that is the avenue which the law expects to be taken, when passing from "I believe somebody owes me money" to any interference with the debtor's property. A court can authorize all sorts of ways for a creditor to be made whole, but if there is no court order then the creditor isn't at liberty to take matters into their own hands. There are clear public policy reasons why society would prefer people to not be constantly taking one another's stuff, etc., under the cloak of "but he owes me money".
The whole arena of debt recovery is subject to a very old and detailed body of law. Generally speaking, it's more common for debtors to be in a vulnerable position compared to their creditors, and that's reflected in how the rules aim to protect debtors from heavy-handed actions. Even in the mediaeval period, a feudal landowner whose tenant was in arrears was obliged to seek recompense out of the tenant's moveable property in the first instance, rather than barring them from the land itself. There are also many rules about giving notice, about the kinds of property which can be seized, and so on. So if the padlocking is conceptualized as an attempt to take control of property in order to enforce payment of the debt, the padlocker is not entitled to proceed in this way. Action requires a court order, to be executed by an approved officer, and holding the premises hostage is in any case not one of the available means.
There is only a very narrow possibility to recover debt outside of the court process, called "summary diligence". This is a sort of pre-agreement by the parties that the creditor is entitled to proceed with diligence (enforcing the debt) on his own initiative. For this to be possible, the underlying written agreement, such as a commercial lease, has to be registered with a court. You then get an already-signed warrant for any sum payable under the agreement, so you don't have to go back to the court later. But even in this case, the warrant is only usable for instructing a sheriff officer to take action: you don't get to personally break down somebody's door and take their TV away merely because you have that piece of paper in your hand.
It is also possible to apply for partial diligence with the court, while the process is still going on. This is called "diligence on the dependence". There is also "inhibition on the dependence" which is the same idea in relation to immoveable property. (That is not a seizure of the land or denying entry to it; it's a matter of preventing it from being sold, etc., without paying the creditor.) It is not automatic but it is a well-expected part of procedure. It would still be necessary to show that granting this interim relief would be reasonable in the circumstances, including that there is a risk that the debtor might hide or lose their assets before the court process concludes. The sum authorized to be collected in this way would be a fraction of the total claim, and it would not be made available to the creditor straight away: this is just about securing the assets, not accelerating the payment.
Turning to the padlock idea - aside from the context of the invoices and so on, there is a question of whether it's a criminal offence to put a padlock on somebody else's gate. In the hypothesis, there is no physical damage to the gate, and so we have not met the bar for the offences of vandalism or malicious mischief. It might be treated as antisocial behavior or harassment from a policing point of view, if we got as far as the police being involved and disposing of the conduct as an offence rather than trying to resolve it some other way. But depending on the circumstances there could be many other offences involved. If the conduct amounts to blocking a fire exit then the padlocker is liable to prosecution (because of the Fire (Scotland) Act 2005, ss.74 and 54(2)(b)) even if there is no fire and nobody is hurt on the day. If it's a gate used by vehicles, and the padlocking causes obstruction of the roadway because the lorries can't get in, then there can also be an offence under the road traffic law. If somebody is locked in the site then this is the offence of abduction, which includes forcible confinement as well as taking people away.
Even if the padlocking is not an offence, it can still be a civil wrong. Note that the Scottish law is different from the "tort" framework used in English and English-derived law. Our concept is "delict" and specifically here damnum iniuria datum, or loss caused by wrongful conduct. Intentionally fixing the padlock in order to cause immediate nuisance (since somebody has to go to the trouble of removing it, perhaps by paying a handyman) and/or consequent economic loss (the premises can't be used until the lock is off) is actionable. The padlocker could be liable in principle for quite a lot of money, depending on how extensively the business was disrupted.
Committing such an offence or delict, in the course of existing litigation over the debt, would not be favourable to that court process, in terms of its outcome, speed of resolution, or total cost.
